# Cascaded XOR gates function for F

Tags: digital-logic

What is the function for F exit in this scheme?

[image]

Comment: If you were after simplfication of boolean algebra with XOR gates I'd recommend this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028688/how-to-simplify-boolean-exression-with-xor

Comment: Correct?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/755yF.gif

Comment: Exactly correct!

Comment: That's all? Or it's possible to write the solution differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the boolean algebra function. It can be represented using only AND \$\bullet\$  and OR \$+\$ as follows:

\$\overline{(A\bullet\overline B + \overline A \bullet B)}\bullet C + (A\bullet\overline B + \overline A \bullet B)\bullet \overline C = F\$

Or using the symbol for XOR \$\oplus\$:

\$(A \oplus B)\oplus C = F \$

Answer (score 2):

F = (A ⊕ B) ⊕ C

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you were after simplfication of boolean algebra with XOR gates I'd recommend this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028688/how-to-simplify-boolean-exression-with-xor

Moved comment to answer as it appears to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think that stating F = (A ⊕ B) ⊕ C does not help much. Making a truth table of this function brings :

F = A or B or C or (A and B and C)

This shows that all entries (A B C) are swapable which is not obvious at first sight...

So F is true if and only if only one entry is true or all of them are true...